# Got ModuleNotFoundError error while running app from docker-compose. How can i solve this?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I got following error while running from docker-compose but it works fine when I run `docker run .` Can some body help me to debug this.
Error:

```
File "/home/desktop/.local/bin/docker-compose", line 5, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..config import ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/config/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .config import ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .validation import match_named_volumes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/compose/config/validation.py", line 8, in <module>
    from jsonschema import Draft4Validator
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from jsonschema._types import TypeChecker
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsonschema/_types.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyrsistent import pmap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrsistent'
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
ENV APP_DIR /home/myapp
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}
ADD requirements.txt ${APP_DIR}/
RUN pip install -r ${APP_DIR}/requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/home/myapp
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    container_name: django_myapp
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
```

While I run `docker-compose build` I get above error. I have Tried adding pyrsistent in requirements.txt but error is still same. How to solve this error??

Comment: That looks like it's a problem in your host's `docker-compose` installation (did you run `pip install` as your normal user?) and not anything in the code you've posted.  In particular note the image uses Python 3.9 but the error message has Python 3.10 paths.

Comment: If its working on your system, try once with the `FROM python:3.9-slim` image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common Python error stack, you need to have some basic knowledge of Python to understand it, but I'll try to explain it briefly here.

The error starts with `/home/desktop/.local/bin/docker-compose` which means it comes from `docker-compose` on the host machine, not from inside `Docker`. The call stack indicates a `compose` -> `jsonschema` -> `pyrsistent` call path and `pyrsistent` is not found (`ModuleNotFoundError`), which means there's a missing dependency on your host machine.

Try `pip3 install docker-compose --user` and `pip3 install pyrsistent --user`:

1. `/home/desktop/.local/bin/docker-compose` indicates your compose was installed to your home directory instead of the system path, so use `--user` to try a local installation.
2. If everything works fine, `pip3 install docker-compose --user` will resolve the whole dependency tree and install `pyrsistent` automatically.
3. If it doesn't work, try the second command to manual fix `pyrsistent` package.
4. If it still fails, try `pip3 install --force-reinstall --user pyrsistent` to reinstall `pyrsistent` package.

Comment: Thank you for help. I stil got same error even after force-reinstall.

Comment: Try to check where the `pip3` installed: `which pip3`, it's possible that you're installing to a different Python runtime from `docker-compose`

Comment: Thank you it worked after I restarted my laptop